# Set Google Analytics User defined value using google measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I started implementing [Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) to my page and i didn't find a way to set "User defined value" within Audience -> Custom -> User Defined.

[image]

I did 2 custom dimensions which works well. I red that this user defined value comes from deprecated custom variables, but i didn't find a way to set it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was set in old ga.js API:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setVar
It seems it is removed now in new analytics.js API. Define custom dimension instead (and find reports under Audience->Custom->Custom Variables).

Comment: I'm talking about measurement protocol, which is not js related